# What should you look for when buying a 100 year old home that has been renovated to look brand new?

Tags: old-house

I am looking to buy a 1900 house with detached garage that has been completely renovated and additions have been added to the house. However, what would be the things to look out for in such an old flipped house?

Comment: Maybe start by looking for a home inspector.

Comment: I 2nd that.  Get a pro.  Even if someone tells you precisely what to look for, you're probably still not qualified to judge it.

Comment: > buy 100yo house > destroy all Victorian gingerbread and anything that gives it character > replace with generic stuff from Home Depot > FLIP > Foreigners go "oooh, ahh, so nice" > locals go /facepalm

Comment: my top anecdotal concerns would be: foundation condition. 4" pipe condition. no knob-and-tube wiring left. grounded outlets. signs of leaking in attic. radon/lead/asbestos assessments.

Comment: Does it have all new/replaced electric and plumbing ? With suitable capacities ?

Answer (score 1):

To start pretty on the outside dont always cut it.Do a look yourself a walk through.Outside roof ok how old; windows old  paint peeling signs of leaks .Next basement look and take notes  foundation type ,plumbing pvc  copper pex look for signs of upgrades.Elec panel look new looks neat not rats nest. Frame looks solid not cut up . Any odd smells damp mold septic.Radon vents dirt floor. Attic insulation ok mold smells ,mice nest. look up at roof any day light. If home still want . Talk to your home inspector about your findings and how deep you want him to look at it.
GET A PRO money well spent.